# Extract svgs from multiple paths

Tags: javascript, svg

here is my code just need to refactor it a bit

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const config = require('../configs/icons.config.js');


const filterDirectory = (file, srcPath) => fs.statSync(path.join(srcPath, file)).isDirectory();

const ensureDirectoryExistence = (filePath) => {
  const dirname = path.dirname(filePath);
  if (fs.existsSync(dirname)) {
    return true;
  }
  ensureDirectoryExistence(dirname);
  return fs.mkdirSync(dirname);
};

const filterExclude = fileName => config.ignore
  .filter(ignore => fileName.indexOf(ignore) >= 0).length === 0;

const getDirectories = srcPath => fs.readdirSync(srcPath)
  .filter(file => filterDirectory(file, srcPath))
  .filter(file => filterExclude(file));

const availableIcons = getDirectories(path.resolve(config.origin));


availableIcons.forEach((file) => {
  ensureDirectoryExistence(path.resolve(`${config.temporary}/${file}`));
  fs.createReadStream(`${config.origin}/${file}/_jcr_content/renditions/original`)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${config.temporary}/${file}`));
});
```

problem is that is want the same  funcionality with

```
const config = require('../configs/globalicons.config.js')
```

if i change the line 3 it is generating new directory for a different config file how to pass both configs at the same time??? like

```
const config = require('../configs/icons.config.js,../configs/globalicons.config.js');
```

not working though

i want to execute the same javascript for 2 different configs 2 generate 2 different directory on a single deployment any tip?